# in "mate-appearance-properties" font tab desktop font is greyed out

Tags: 20.04, fonts, mate, ubuntu-mate

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 Mate desktop. I noticed that in `mate-appearance-properties`' fonts tab `desktop font` is greyed out and inactive, I can't select a font. I also created another user, it's the same in that login. I also ran it with `sudo`, nothing is changed.

Is it a new bug or something wrong in my system?

EDIT:

```
apt show mate-control-center       
Package: mate-control-center
Version: 1.24.0-1
```

I can set `Desktop Font` with `gsettings set org.mate.caja.desktop font 'Sans Regular 10'` but it's not updated  in `"mate-appearance-properties`'s fonts tab  I think `mate-control-center` can't reach it or it stems from a broken schema in my system.

[image]

EDIT2:

```
 ls -al ~/.config/dconf/user
-rw-rw-r-- 1 kenn kenn 103646 Jan 29 18:36 /home/kenn/.config/dconf/user
```

Comment: Your window border looks strange. I would recommend to install full version of Ubuntu MATE by `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop^` and then retry.

Comment: @N0rbert I use `compiz` window manager with `emerald` window decorator, both of them are from official repositories.

Comment: @N0rbert  Reinstalling `ubuntu-mate-desktop` didn't work.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue on VM with no luck. So you are welcome back to UMC, let's wait for reaction from other users there (or maybe here too).

Comment: @N0rbert Thank you for your efforts, I think Desktop Font is set by `gsettings set org.mate.caja.desktop font 'Sans Regular 10'` I can set it via command line but I think mate-control-center can't reach it or there is a broken schema in my system.

Comment: You can try to fix the gschema by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall caja-common` . Also please add output of `ls -al ~/.config/dconf/user` to the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Though this post doesn't answer what caused that weird behaviour, I found a workaround.

I reinstalled whole Mate packages with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-mate-desktop^` but it didn't work.
I can set Desktop Font with `gsettings set org.mate.caja.desktop font 'Sans Regular 8'` but it's not updated in `mate-appearance-properties`'s fonts tab,
it's still showing `Sans Regular 12` in greyed out state but `gsettings` command changes the `desktop font`.
I can read it via `dconf read /org/mate/caja/desktop/font`
it prints 'Sans Regular 8'

**I still don't know what triggered that bug but I fixed it by reverting changes manually which committed in 2014.**

With that commit [Use Caja GSettings schema optionally](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-control-center/commit/ac5bfbfd01210309674bd946f09f576773d06917)  `caja`'s function became optional.
I downloaded `mate-control-center`'s source code from original repository with
`apt source mate-control-center`, I opened files and inserted or deleted required lines.
Then `dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -us -uc` and installed `deb` packages on desktop with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

`mate-appearance-properties` is OK now.